# Module translations import manually or when module activation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've created a simple module and needed to add some translations messages.

Next step was to create a "translations" folder with a po file named "pt-pt.po" inside (my language defined is pt-pt) and programmatically didn't worry to import those messages.

I thought that those messages were imported when module activation but that didn't happen.

I thought wrongly? :) Or what I'm missing?

I have to import manually per-environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does the pt-pt.po file contain strings (I don't understand from that programmatically part)? If not, you'll need something like this http://drupal.org/project/potx to extract the strings from your module.

If the translation file has strings but those were not imported keep in mind that the translations are read and imported only when a module is installed, not activated. So if the module was activated after it was deactivated at some point then the translations will not be re-read.

In this case this could solve the issue: http://drupal.org/project/po_re_importer.